# How do I rewrite $\int {dx\over \sqrt x\log x}$ in with $u$-substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I write:

$$\int {dx\over \sqrt x\log x}$$

In terms of $u$:

$$\int {du \over \log u} \quad u = \sqrt x$$

I'm given the substitution for $u$, but I cannot reduce it further than $\int {2du\over \log x}$. How would I rewrite fully in terms of $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u = \sqrt x \quad du = {1\over 2 \sqrt x}dx \quad dx = 2\sqrt x du$$

Thus, rewriting in terms of $u$:

$$\require{cancel} \begin{align} \int {dx \over \sqrt x \log x} &= \int {1\over \cancel{\sqrt x} \log x} 2\cancel{\sqrt x} du \\
&= \int {2\over \log x} du \\
\end{align}$$

Now, you can do some rewriting:

$$\begin{align} \int {2\over \log x} du &= \int {1\over {1\over 2} \log x} du \\
&= \int {1\over \log x^{\frac 12}} du \\
&= \int {1\over \log \sqrt x} du \\
&= \int {1\over \log u} du \\
\end{align}$$

Remember the log property $\log\left(a^b\right) = b\log(a)$. That's how you rewrite $\frac 12 \log x$ as $\log \sqrt x$, and thus $\log u$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log x=2\log\sqrt x{}{}{}{}$$